# Temporarily Disable Workflow On Single List Item

Tags: 2013, workflow

I would like to modify a single list item, but I don't want the workflow to run, nor do I want to pause workflow for the entire list.

How can I temporarily disable workflow on a specific list item, make some changes, and then re-enable workflow on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get SPListItem via powershell, set property and update item without firing event, see example below:

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
 if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
$web  = Get-SPWeb "http://dev2"
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$item = $list.Items.GetItemById(1)


$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint");
$type = $assembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager");
$prop = $type.GetProperty([string]"EventFiringDisabled",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags] ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static));

$prop.SetValue($null, $true, $null); #Disable event firing

$item["Title"] = "Changed withou firing events"
$item.SystemUpdate($false)

$prop.SetValue($null, $false, $null);#Enable event firing
```

Comment: You should always wrap it into a tra/catch.