# SharePoint 2013, updating lots of records, by script?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, script

I have a SharePoint list that has lots of columns and a priority column.

Now it used to be a high - medium - low column.

However last year they changed the ideas behind that, and we have now 1,2,3,4 as priority.

Its all working nice, but when I now filter on items the old values still appear. They should translate `high=1` and `medium = 2` and `low = 4`

The problem there are a lot of records, I need a way to automatically update those values. And only change them if they have the old high-medium-low status.

Update some code, as related to powershell scripting this
Some how this code doesnt work i dont see whats wrong with it.
Its just a first step to only show something so i see the lists is traversed

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
$webURL = "https://infodesk.company.com"
$listName = "Tickets"
$web = Get-SPWeb -site $webURL
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$items = $list.items
Foreach($item in $items)
{
  Echo $item
}
```

Comment: Do you need c# console code or javascript?

Comment: As this is one time activity, you can use powershell for this.

Comment: Remember, when you update items all Modified dates will be set to current time as well

Comment: and Modified By also will be set to current logged in user

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell it would go something like this, assuming you're replacing value in same field.

If you need to update other field with the new value, just update the field name inside the IF statements:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$webURL = "https://site.company.com"
$listName = "yourlistname"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$items = $list.items

Foreach($item in $items)
{
    if($item["PriorityColumn"] -eq "high")
    {
        $item["PriorityColumn"] = "1"    
    }    
    elseif($item["PriorityColumn"] -eq "medium")
    {
        $item["PriorityColumn"] = "2"
    }
    elseif($item["PriorityColumn"] -eq "low")
    {
        $item["PriorityColumn"] = "4"
    }    

    $item.SystemUpdate($false)
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: ehm if $item.update() is used modified column will change, shouldnt i use $item.SystemUpdate($false) instead ?.

Comment: That is correct, use SystemUpdate if you don't want Modified, ModifiedBy reflect this update, as well as don't want to create new versions if versioning is enabled.

Comment: Is there something to disable workflows as well (just to be sure)

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94362/temporarily-disable-workflow-on-single-list-item

Comment: Okay tried it all together now, but its not working,.. That $ListName, is that the friendly name or should it be an url as well ?.
Somehow i dont see any error

Comment: $ListName is the title of the list, so not URL.

Comment: in main question i put some test code, (not altering anything) but its not working

Comment: You have added -site parameter in Get-SPWeb, remove it as in my code example, so just $web = Get-SPWeb $webURL

Comment: that was actually an attempt to solve it, maybe i should start from here to get my list items http://www.robertkuzma.com/2012/09/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell-script/ that seams to work

Comment: Tested my code in my dev env, and it works fine.

Comment: i created an answer complete script below, not sure why yours didnt work (it seams all valid to me)

Answer (score 1):

Thank to [@Jussi palo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/6497/jussi-palo), I got the basic idea for the script.
I eventually ended up using the script below for some unknown reason the selection of items didn't work (maybe because it wasn't a standard SharePoint column?, well I can only guess.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

#disable event firing
$myAss =    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint");
$type = $myAss.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager");
$prop = $type.GetProperty([string]"EventFiringDisabled",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags] ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static));
$prop.SetValue($null, $true, $null);

$sourceWebURL = "https://infodesk.company.com/IT"
$sourceListName = "Tickets"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]

$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Priority'] -eq 'NORMAL'}

[int]$count = 0
ForEach($item in $spSourceItems)
{
  $status = $item['Priority']
  if($status = "NORMAL")
  {
    $count++
    Write-Host $count, $item['Priority'],$item['Title']

    #Unmark below to activate this script
    #$item["Priority"] = "3"
    #$item.SystemUpdate($false)  #this updates without changing modified
    #Write-Host $item['Priority'],$item['Title']
  }
}
# enable event firing
$prop.SetValue($null, $false, $null);
```

Comment: It is really an answer to your question?

Comment: All the same as my script.

Comment: The differences are indeed minimal, so i'm not sure why this one works and the other didnt, but did work in your case, i wasnt getting the column items back; maybe cause its a custom column by a vendor (not standard sharepoint column).

Comment: @Aakash Morya Yes it is, around 500 wrong entries have been corrected with it in just 10 sec. To do it safely i first did a run to list the names, then altered code (unmarked) to set values i did this per wrong priority entry.
Could have done it all in once, but i just play on the safe side.
Without the script doing it manually would have altered modified column what would have resulted in wrong reports.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code to change the `PriorityColumn` (Your columns name) values from `high` to `1`.

**You can do same for other values like medium & low for by changing the parameters in query.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var collListItemToBeUpdated = "";
    var listItemToBeUpdated = "";
    function getItemsToBeUpdated() <--- this function called on button click to get ID's
    {
         var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('rohit_list1');
         var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
         camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where>' +
            '<FieldRef Name=\'PriorityColumn\'/><Value Type=\'text\'>high</Value>' +
            '</Where></Query></View>');
         collListItemToBeUpdated = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdated);
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed);
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess()
    {
         ListItemToBeUpdated= collListItemToBeUpdated.getEnumerator();
         updateMultipleListItems();
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed(sender, args)
    {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function updateMultipleListItems() <--- this function called on successfully getting ID's
    {   
        var itemArray = [];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('rohit_list1');

         while(ListItemToBeUpdated.moveNext())
         {
            var oItem = ListItemToBeUpdated.get_current();
            var oListItem = oList.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
            oListItem.set_item('PriorityColumn', '1');  
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray.push(oListItem);
            clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
         }  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(updateMultipleListItemsSuccess, updateMultipleListItemsFailed);
    }
    function updateMultipleListItemsSuccess() 
    {    
        alert('Items Updated');
    }

    function updateMultipleListItemsFailed(sender, args) 
    {    
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: is given solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a script? Are there hundreds or thousands record that you need to update? If the amount of items is not that big it is a lot easier, especially of you are not a developer, to do it manually using Excel. Try doing the following:

- Create a view that only shows items with old priority values
- Export list the Excel
- Perform search and replace in your excel sheet
- Copy the updated values to SharePoint using the Quick Edit mode (also using the view you used for exporting). You can copy only the Priority column so other columns are not updated.

Comment: i have 523 records..